# Посоветуйте хороший визуализатор по java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

Нашел один хороший - [Sourcetrail](https://www.sourcetrail.com/), но он не работает(ошибка 87, не найдена java-либа, подозреваю что ему нужна eclipse-jdt). Есть еще похожие?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы в какой IDE то сидите? )

Comment: @Suvitruf IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [Plantuml плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration) для работы с [plantuml](http://plantuml.com/) в IDEA.

Хотя, вроде и в стандартных [диаграммах](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/diagrams.html) есть [диаграммы классов](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html).

Comment: В 2018.2.1 идее способы по ссылкам не работают, а расширение посмотрю позже.

Comment: Хм, так это же для Ultimate идеи? А расширение у меня так и не заработало...

Answer (score 0):

еще бесплатный редактор [SciaReto](https://sciareto.org) имеет встроенную поддержку редактирования и рендера PlantUML